# Logo in navigation bar positioning

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know there are a lot of questions about this, I've tried some of them and I didn't have that much luck.

I have this structure:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">
          <a><img style="height: 50px;" src="https://user94.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/ubuntu-logo.png"></a>
       </div>
  <div class="header-content"> 
    <nav> 
      <a href="#section-one">About me</a>
      <a href="#section-two">Education</a>
      <a href="#section-three">Personal life</a>
      <a href="#section-four">My work</a>
      <a href="#section-five">Contact me</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;

  align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080) no-repeat 10% 10% / cover;
}

.header-content {
  margin-top: 2em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}



.logo{
padding-right: 0; 
}

nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(49, 41, 61);
  font-size: .8em;
  margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left: 30em;
}
```

I'm trying to move the logo to the left without affecting my navigation items to the right, I was so much in trouble getting the nav items to the right and over the image that I don't get how to make both of them positioned correctly.

How can I make it work?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLMzpO

Comment: I don't understand why your `firex-direction` is `column`. Do you want them stacked on top of the other or do you want the logo on the left and the `<nav>` on the right?

Comment: what style are you looking for? I noticed you have `flex-direction: column` for your header so this will stack them. If you remove this, it will use `row` as flex and you will get your logo to the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS for `header` should do what you want:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080) no-repeat 10% 10% / cover;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjRQRV

(no `column` direction, `justify-content: space-between;` and `align-items: baseline;` are the essential changes to your version)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
.logo{
padding-right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.logo img{
  opacity: 0;
}
.logo::after{
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 54px;
  opacity: 0.99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  background: url("https://user94.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/ubuntu-logo.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in navigation bar you should use `flex-direction: row`.
here is a useful link [flexbox basic navigation - menu items and logo](https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/XJqmXW)

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080) no-repeat 10% 10% / cover;
}

.header-content {
  margin-top: 2em;
}


header a,
header a:visited {
  color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #FA26BF;
  
}

.logo{
padding-right: 0;
}

.logo img{
  
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(49, 41, 61);
  font-size: .8em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-left: 30em;
}

nav a {
  margin: 1em;

}

nav a,
nav a:visited {
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:active {
  color: #FA26BF;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="logo">
          <a><img style="height: 50px;" src="https://user94.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/ubuntu-logo.png"></a>
       </div>
  <div class="header-content"> 
    <nav> 
      <a href="#section-one">About me</a>
      <a href="#section-two">Education</a>
      <a href="#section-three">Personal life</a>
      <a href="#section-four">My work</a>
      <a href="#section-five">Contact me</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```